# Uploading image to server and displaying its name on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are similar questions and have some very good answers. Because I am new to iOS it is becoming difficult for me to understand that syntax and logic. I have a text field and a button for uploading image with it. I need to show the name of picked image in that text field.

**Method for uploading image:**

```
- (IBAction)btn_uploadPic:(id)sender {
    _picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _picker.delegate = self;
    _picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The other method I have is posting the data on the server correctly. I just need to add image uploading to it. Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)btn_ideaSubmit:(id)sender {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/fundme/public/api/v1/createIdea"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postIdea =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&idea_info=%@&idea_location=%@&idea_description=%@&idea_title=%@&selection=%@", _text_ideaInfo.text , _txt_ideaLocation.text , _txt_ideaDescription.text, _txt_idea.text, _txt_ideaCommunity.text];
    NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", postIdea);
    NSData *data1 = [postIdea dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:data1];
    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
    if(resSrt)
    {
        NSLog(@"Data Posted Successfully");
    }   else
        {
            NSLog(@"failed to connect");
        }
}
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: photo in the user's photo library don't have a name :( . There filename is hidden to you. As for the server part... well it depends on your server, but , if you are a beginner,you should consider using AFNetworking or at lest NSURLSession... NSURLConnection is definitely outdated, hard, and a pain in the Keyboard

Comment: @WajahatHashmi There is some metadata on `PHAsset`, the data type used for photos, that may be useful to you like the creation date and location.

Comment: @Florian Burel, The isssue is that i am using old version of iOS and if you see the examples on net. It is of `AFNetworking 2.0 or 3.0` and i only managed to add `AFNetworking 1.0` Thats why its becoming difficult.

Comment: AFNetworking 1 still works better that NSURLConnection. Fact is, AFNetworking 1.0 was invented because NSURLConnection is painful to use.

Comment: Also any new project should target iOS 7 minimum... No need to support iOS 5.x, 6.x... As you can see here : https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/ only 3% of iOS device run on a iOS version older than 8.X ... Especially if your new to the objC thingy, newer api makes it way easier.